# Defer merged css in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, optimization, pagespeed, merge-css

I need to Defer merged css using JavaScript. Is there any possibilities to defer merged css. Example code i want to do.

```
    <noscript id="deferred-styles">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxx.xx/static/version1xxxx/_cache/merged/f64d21109ccdd1dc8924b35f2614e40f.min.css"/>
    </noscript>
```

```
<script>
  var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
    var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
    var replacement = document.createElement("div");
    replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(replacement)
    addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
  };
  var raf = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
  else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
</script>
```

Comment: Is there no one can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I have a method that works but I'm not 100% confident I'm using best practices. The functions that merge and add CSS to the site header are in the Magento Framework module:

```
Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer
```

The functions you need to edit are protected so we have to use preferences instead of say, a plugin. Make a new module in app/code/[Vendor]/[Namespace] with the usual files:

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[Vendor]_[Namespace]',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Vendor]_[Namespace]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Framework" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer" type="[Vendor]\[Namespace]\View\Page\Config\Renderer" />
</config>
```

Last thing is to make this file and copy all the Magento code in to it:

```
[Vendor]\[Namespace]\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php
```

copy the code from:

```
vendor\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php
```

You'll need to update the namespace and class definitions:

```
...
namespace [Vendor]\[Namespace]\View\Page\Config;
...
class Renderer implements \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\RendererInterface
```

And then you can get to customising the functions inside. I followed the Google page speed guide on deferring CSS by altering these two functions as follows:

```
/**
 * Add default attributes
 *
 * @param string $contentType
 * @param string $attributes
 * @return string
 */
protected function addDefaultAttributes($contentType, $attributes)
{
    if ($contentType === 'js') {
        return ' type="text/javascript" ' . $attributes;
    }

    if ($contentType === 'css') {
        return ' rel="preload" type="text/css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel=\'stylesheet\'" ' . ($attributes ?: ' media="all"');
    }

    if ($this->canTypeBeFont($contentType)) {
        return 'rel="preload" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous"';
    }

    return $attributes;
}
```

and..

```
/**
 * Render HTML tags referencing corresponding URLs
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup $group
 * @return string
 */
protected function renderAssetHtml(\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup $group)
{
    $assets = $this->processMerge($group->getAll(), $group);
    $attributes = $this->getGroupAttributes($group);

    $result = '';
    $template = '';
    try {
        /** @var $asset \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\AssetInterface */
        foreach ($assets as $asset) {
            $template = $this->getAssetTemplate(
                $group->getProperty(GroupedCollection::PROPERTY_CONTENT_TYPE),
                $this->addDefaultAttributes($this->getAssetContentType($asset), $attributes)
            );
            if ($group->getProperty(GroupedCollection::PROPERTY_CONTENT_TYPE) === 'css') {
                $result .= sprintf($template, $asset->getUrl(), $asset->getUrl());
            } else {
                $result .= sprintf($template, $asset->getUrl());
            }
        }
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->logger->critical($e);
        $result .= sprintf($template, $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('', ['_direct' => 'core/index/notFound']));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

It seemed to satisfy the Lighthouse tool but it's not tested thoroughly. Good luck with this!

**EDIT:**
This change affects the backend CSS loading as well... not ideal but not website breaking.

Comment: When I tested this I got: Error: Class '****\DeferCss\View\Page\Config\Generator\Head' not found in /app/code/****/DeferCss/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php:

Comment: You might need to run setup:upgrade (and di:compile in production)

Comment: Tried that no joy sadly